# Caught Exception while registering Interceptor class org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor

Tags: struts2, struts

I am trying to deploy the Struts 2.1.6 EAR file into Websphere 7 and getting the error. I already updated validators.xml with the latest (Struts) DTDs but still facing an issue.

Comment: Caused by: Caught Exception while registering Interceptor class org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor - interceptor - wsjar:file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrvHSCS/installedApps/IBM-7eee9b3778eNode02Cell/acys-hscs.ear/acys-hscs-web.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.1.6.jar!/struts-default.xml:146:127
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildInterceptor(ObjectFactory.java:202)

Comment: Don't add code in comments, post full stack trace, add a code example to reproduce a problem.